# How to use pagination in strapi.js when accessing relational content?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I have a `CourseSeries` table that has `title`, `description`, and is linked to many `courses`

[image]

When I visit `http://localhost:1338/course-series` I get:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "series X",
    "description": null,
    "courses": [....] // e.g. 100 entries (I want to be able to do `?_limit=10` on courses)
  },
  { "id: 3,...},
  ...
]
```

Is there a way to limit the number of `courses` that show up?